# Problem in splitting lists with different delimiters

Tags: python

I'm solving an exercise where I take seconds as an input and I got to return the amount of time in years, days, hours, minutes and seconds.

For example:

[The components are separated by a comma and a space (", "). Except the last component, which is separated by " and ", just like it would be written in English.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0m5t.png)

However, I am not being able to format the data in the format that is required to pass the tests, as I can either only do comma's or and's, not both.

[This code generates: 2 days and 4 hours and 56 minutes and 4 seconds]

```
def format_duration(seconds):
    result = []
    counter = 0
    if seconds == 0:
        print('now')
        return 'now'
    final_years = int(seconds/31536000)
    final_days = (int(seconds/86400))%365
    final_hours = (int(seconds/3600))%24
    final_minutes = (int(seconds/60))%60
    final_seconds = seconds%60
    returning(final_years,' year',result)
    returning(final_days,' day',result)
    returning(final_hours,' hour',result)
    returning(final_minutes,' minute',result)
    returning(final_seconds,' second',result)
    print(' and '.join(result))
    return ' and '.join(result)

def returning(time,name,array):
    if time > 0:
        if time == 1:
            array.append(str(time)+name)           
        if time > 1:
            name += 's'
            array.append(str(time)+name)

format_duration(190564)
```

I have tried making a counter to understand how many commas and ands would be needed but I struggle to add them to the sections necessary afterwards.

Comment: You don't need to split anything. You're asking how you can _join_ items in a list with different delimiters

Comment: Gotcha, I wasnt really sure how to word the problem that i have

Comment: Checkout [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

Comment: The [inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) module has useful tools for these sorts of sentence constructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define your plural function to accept the value and the name, and *return the correctly formatted string*. No need to mess about with lists passed to the function. We will check if a value is zero *before* passing it to the `plural` function.

```
def plural(value, name):
    if value == 1:
        return f"1 {name}"
    else:
        return f"{value} {name}s"
```

Next, inside your `format_duration`, create a list of all the pluralized strings, filtering out values that are zero. Finally, join all but the last element of this list with a comma, and the last element with an `and`:

```
def format_duration(seconds):
    result = []
    counter = 0
    if seconds == 0:
        return 'now'

    labels = ["year", "day", "hour", "minute", "second"]

    final_years = int(seconds/31536000)
    final_days = (int(seconds/86400))%365
    final_hours = (int(seconds/3600))%24
    final_minutes = (int(seconds/60))%60
    final_seconds = seconds%60

    formatted_vals = [plural(v, n) 
                      for v, n in zip(
                                      [final_years, final_days, final_hours, final_minutes, final_seconds],
                                      labels
                                     )
                      if v != 0]
    if len(formatted_vals) == 1:
        return formatted_vals[0]

    return ", ".join(formatted_vals[:-1]) + " and " + formatted_vals[-1]
```

Comment: A missed corner case is that `format_duration(58)` returns `' and 58 seconds'`. Another corner case is `format_duration(0)`, but it's not clear if that should return `'0 seconds'` or an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @Steven. `format_duration(0)` returns `'now'`, I just retained that from OP's code